# How do I remove the Ubuntu installation USB without having problems?

Tags: 19.04, usb-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 19. 04 from a USB, but I'm afraid of corrupting the system if I take it out, because it gives me that there are files of the Ubuntu system. How can I take it out without corrupting the system and gives me errors?

Thank you very much :D

Comment: Your description "it gives me that there are files of the Ubuntu system" is confusing. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1159564/edit) to clarify.  What, exactly, leads you to believe that removing the USB would lead to corruption? And corruption of what?

Comment: When installation is finished it should tell you to remove the USB in order to reboot your system.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix When the installation finishes it doesn't ask me to remove the USB, and when I removed it before the OS gave me many problems.

Comment: Repeat the installation and allow it to complete this time.

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix . It worked for me.

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted an answer in case others experience the same. kindly click the grey check mark next to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per comments:

> Repeat the installation but do not remove USB until complete.